# Making with Microsoft Graph an OnlineMeeting object error 403

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

Im doing and application with PHP, which use Microsoft Graph API. Actually i couldnt found any documentation for php, so im follow microsoft tutorial.

So first i tried to do the microsoft page example for post method:

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/app/onlineMeetings
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 1553

```
{
  "meetingType": "meetNow",
  "participants": {
    "organizer": {
      "identity": {
        "user": {
          "id": <id user azuread teenant>
      }
    }
  }
},
 "subject": "subject-value"
```

}

actually it doesnt work on microsoft graph explorer. I already gave all permissions and ir returns the following:

Failure - Status Code 403, 440ms Looks like you may not have the permissions for this call.

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "Forbidden",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "fd8cdedd-99f1-4bca-9de6-29a77f834bba",
        "date": "2019-04-25T18:06:43"
        }
    }
}
```

I though explorer dont work with onlinemeetings and calls, so i stopped to use it, and i tried on a php app.

Then i tried this:

```
// Create a Graph client
// Set  graph version
// Get user info
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);   
$graph->setApiVersion("beta");

$createTeamsUrl = '/app/onlineMeetings';

$events = $graph->createRequest('POST', $createTeamsUrl)
->attachBody($body)
->execute();
```

accessToken is the returned token from oauth v2.0, and it works.

I already gave to my azure ad aaplication all permissions for test purpuoses (including delegated and app such as OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All), but this returns the same error.

I did some others request, like this:

```
//works
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($accessToken->getToken());

$user = $graph->createRequest('GET', '/me')
->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
->execute();
```

and this works.

I also downloaded c# sample, and it works, so i think its not permissions

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/

If anyone knows if this is supported or not, could be useful.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Fernando, were you able to found a solution on this? I got the same problem in NodeJS too.

Comment: Hello friend, yes i did. im gonna update this in a while

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `common` as tenant to get the access token, first thing you have to do is use your tenant id instead of common word, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276045/solved-getting-forbidden-when-try-to-create-an-online-meeting-using-microsoft-g). This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create and grant an [Online Meeting Application policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy). This is mentioned in the permissions section of [Online Meeting-Get documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0), but it is not highlighted or called out as a gotcha.

Here is a rough outline for creating and granting an Application Policy:

1. Install the MicrosoftTeams powershell commandlets (previously 2 separate module installs were required!)
2. Import the microsoftTeams module into the current powershell session.
3. Log in/connect to microsoftTeams with an admin account
4. Create a policy containing one or more application IDs
5. Grant that policy to one or more users.

<opinion> *The tools for setting up an Application Policy are confusing (poorly integrated?), so be prepared for some frustration.*</opinion>

This allowed me to move forward to a new error.

Answer (score -1):

Getting same 403 forbidden error on creating online meeting
also added "OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All" permission in the scope

[image]

[image]

Comment: this should be a comment to the question and not an answer